# Find Character Location in Text Component (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to find the location (x and y offset from origin of the component) of specific characters in my multiline text component. I've tried using the `onLayout` prop of my nested text components, but that function is never called for nested text. Is there a method for calculating the x and y of specific characters (based on index) within a string that are being rendered in a `<Text>` component with a defined width and height?

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
const renderString = `
Here is a multiline string that I am rendering. I would like a method for finding the x 
and y position of specific characters within this string when rendered in a text component.
`

const height = 400;
const width = 400;

function findCharacterPosition() {
    // How do I write this function?
}

function Comp() {
    return (
        <View style={{width, height}}>
            <Text>
                {renderString}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution. First you need to choose a monospace font so characters are equal width, then you need to find out the ratio of fontSize to actual character width. To find this ratio, create a view with a `<Text>` child with a single text character, set its `onLayout` prop and find out the width of the view, this will be the width of a single character with the test font size. The
measured width over fontSize gives you the ratio. Multiply ratio by your font size to find actual character size for that font and font size. Then you need calculate which line and character position using some maths, then use the measurements to determine position.